# PayPal integrated iOS 8 App

Tags: ios, objective-c, paypal

I have downloaded and played with the github project for the paypal ios app.
https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK
I ran it just fine without any errors. When I try to link it into my iOS 8 swift project I can load all the files and connect the view controllers just fine and I believe my bridge header file is working just fine. I basically moved all the viewcontroller files from the sample app into my project and just connected what I needed to. I have the client id and secret id working I believe. It is when I try to create a FuturePaymentViewController :

```
 - (IBAction)getUserAuthorizationForFuturePayments:(id)sender {

       NSLog(@"\n\n\nbegin getting user authorization\n\n\nPAYPAL CONFIG::::   %@", self.payPalConfig);
       PayPalFuturePaymentViewController *futurePaymentViewController = [[PayPalFuturePaymentViewController alloc] initWithConfiguration:self.payPalConfig delegate:self];

       //breaks here when trying to send the config init.


        NSLog(@"\n\n\nafter initializtion of paypal future payment view controller\n\n\n");

        [self presentViewController:futurePaymentViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
        NSLog(@"after present");
 }
```

Error I get is :

```
 PAYPAL CONFIG::::   <PayPalConfiguration: 0x7fb23e212af0>


 2014-10-12 16:31:38.979 Project[2161:69146] -[PayPalFuturePaymentViewController       payPalServiceManager]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fb23e2207d0
 2014-10-12 16:31:38.981 Project[2161:69146] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception     'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[PayPalFuturePaymentViewController payPalServiceManager]:      unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fb23e2207d0'
 *** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001055bf3f5 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000105258bb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001055c650d -[NSObject(NSObject)     doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010551e7fc ___forwarding___ + 988
4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010551e398 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
5   CutInLineSwift                      0x000000010262c0b1 -[PayPalFuturePaymentViewController initWithConfiguration:delegate:] + 361
6   CutInLineSwift                      0x00000001025d28de -[ZZMainViewController getUserAuthorizationForFuturePayments:] + 190
7   UIKit                               0x00000001029639ee -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 75
8   UIKit                               0x0000000102a69bd0 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 467
9   UIKit                               0x0000000102a68f9f -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 522
10  UIKit                               0x00000001029a93b8 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 735
11  UIKit                               0x00000001029a9ce3 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 683
12  UIKit                               0x0000000102976ae1 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 246
13  UIKit                               0x0000000102983bad _UIApplicationHandleEventFromQueueEvent + 17370
14  UIKit                               0x000000010295f233 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 1961
15  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001054f4ad1 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
16  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001054ea99d __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 269
17  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001054e9fd4 __CFRunLoopRun + 868
18  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001054e9a06 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
19  GraphicsServices                    0x00000001071eb9f0 GSEventRunModal + 161
20  UIKit                               0x0000000102962550 UIApplicationMain + 1282
21  CutInLineSwift                      0x00000001025d093e top_level_code + 78
22  CutInLineSwift                      0x00000001025d097a main + 42
23  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000105f93145 start + 1
 )
  libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

This should not be breaking since no different from the sample project but I have no idea why it is. Please help me, thank you!

Comment: It looks like something isn't being linked or a header isn't imported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dave from PayPal here.

I believe that your problem will be solved by step 3 of our [integration instructions](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK#add-the-sdk-to-your-project):

> In your project's **Build Settings** (in the `TARGETS` section, not the `PROJECTS` section):
>
> - add `-lc++ -ObjC` to `Other Linker Flags`

Also, please note [Step 1](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK/blob/master/docs/future_payments_mobile.md#obtain-customer-consent) of our sample code, which indicates that you must call `[PayPalMobile initializeWithClientIdsForEnvironments:]` to initialize the SDK, prior to calling other methods.

Comment: I have step 3 complete for the targets adding -lc++. Where do I call that method when I have this method in Swift within my app delegate.
     
PayPalMobile.initializeWithClientIdsForEnvironments([PayPalEnvironmentProduction: "XXXXXXXX", PayPalEnvironmentSandbox: "XXXXXXXXX"])

Comment: Actually, it was the missing `-ObjC` that was responsible for your problem. (Though adding `-lc++` is also important.) Re the `initializeWithClientIdsForEnvironments:` method, your app delegate is indeed the correct place to call it.

Comment: YES YES Thank you it was the -ObjC!! Thank you!

Comment: So to add to this, that did fix my issue but turns out something in the FacebookSDK/ParseSDK and the Paypal mobile SDK have conflicting instances or files and causing the issues.

Comment: @JMStudios.jrichardson could you be more specific about what these conflicts are?

Comment: From what I remember and researched is conflicting class names, interface names and or file names. Mainly when I had PayPalMobile in my project and would then try to bring in ParseSDK the error would occur, I think it was either the BoltsFramework conflicting with something in the PayPalMobile or the FacebookSDK conflicting with PayPalMobile.

Comment: Well, if you ever return to that project, and can show us precise error messages, then maybe we could do something to improve the situation.

Comment: I think this is the stackoverflow post I made about it.    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26519552/paypal-and-parse-conflicting.
If that isn't helpful for you then I will try and re-create the issue early next week for you.

Comment: Do you need more information about the error from me?

Comment: @JMStudios.jrichardson the errors shown in that other StackOverflow post indicate missing Parse symbols. I don't see any errors there regarding PayPal-iOS-SDK symbols.

Comment: I get those errors anytime I try to integrate PayPal-iOS-SDK with Parse. I tried making the Parse systems working first then integrate PayPal still same errors then I started over and completed the PayPal system, then when I tried to integrate Parse I would get the same error. I was able to get parse working by itself.

Comment: @JMStudios.jrichardson at which step in integrating PayPal do these errors begin to appear? Is it when you add the `-ObjC` linker flag? Do the makers of Parse have any suggestions for you? Given that the problematic symbols are from Parse and not PayPal, there is little help *I* can give you.

Comment: The error occurs when trying to add in the frameworks of Parse or Paypal to my project. Either drag and drop frameworks or go through link binary files the error occurs then.