# PayPal and Parse Conflicting

Tags: ios, paypal, parse-platform

Trying to use PayPal iOS SDK able to get it working with just Paypal integration but when I try to add any of the parse needed frameworks such as Parse.framework, Boltz.framework and ParseFacebookUtils.framework I get the error:

```
ld: symbols(s) not found for architecture i386
clang:error:linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

These are the frameworks I have to use for the PayPal iOS SDK:

```
 SystemConfigureation.framework
 MobileCoreServices.framework
 MessageUI.framework
 CoreLocation.framework
 CoreMedia.framework
 AVFoundation.framework
 AudioToolbox.framework
```

I have looked through various forums and would find answers saying conflicting iterface names or class names but that is not the case, I went through the frameworks and didn't see any of the same names. I am at a loss. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What symbols are not found? Could you include more of the log output?

Comment: Have you done all these steps? https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK#add-the-sdk-to-your-project

Comment: @BlackRider - For some reason I tried running it again this morning to get the log message but instead it compiled and ran with nothing changed. When I check my frameworks folder it has the included frameworks for parse and paypal but does not show the frameworks in the build settings linked binary files. Once I tried to use parse in my app delegate to try to use parse I get this new error:

Comment: @BlackRider - 

ld: warning: Auto-Linking supplied '/Users/josephrichardson/Downloads/parse-library-1.4.2/Parse.framework/Parse', framework linker option at /Users/josephrichardson/Downloads/parse-library-1.4.2/Parse.framework/Parse is not a dylib
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Parse", referenced from:
      __TMaCSo5Parse in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: @AsifAsif - yes followed all

Comment: Has anyone tried using paypal and parse.com in a iOS app? Does anyone have any other ideas?